i want to get to velocity to zero, but i am getting this error: "setting linear velocity of a kinematic body is not supported" how can i solve?
i am trying to get velocity to zero of a gameObject for not to move it but i can't handle it because getting that error on header. is there a any way to get velocity to zero?
i have try these methods but they aren't working at all:

float velocityChangeSpeed = 10f;  objectRigidbody.velocity = Vector3.Lerp(objectRigidbody.velocity, Vector3.zero, velocityChangeSpeed);

objectRigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;



Well the error tells you your object is kinematic .. so setting it's velocity makes no sense ... Rather stop whatever is moving it by code or animation ...

@derHugo what is the meaning of kinematic? also how to stop the gameobject by code ?

Kinematic in this particular case means "not affected by physics". So you're the one who will have to manipulate it. And that of course means that "velocity" has no meaning anymore.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Use the MovePosition function for Kinematic Objects.
To learn more check the docs on what a Kinematic Object is, when to use it, and how to use it:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Rigidbody2D-Kinematic.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html
